# nVidia Settings: Overriding anti-aliasing causes delay

Tags: wine

I'm using Google Sketchup on ubuntu 12.04 with Wine 1.4. It works flawlessly out of the box, but anti-aliasing is causing some problems.

I can override anti-aliasing settings using the nVidia X Server Settings utility, which results in a great-looking image. However, the view doesn't seem to update properly. It's a bit hard to explain, but if I do something (e.g. zooming) the changes won't appear in the view until I take another action. in other words, there seems to be a delay of one "action". Take this example.

1. The mouse wheel is moved one notch to zoom in one step. Nothing happens.
2. An object is selected by clicking. The new zoom is rendered but the selection box doesn't appear.
3. An empty area is clicked. The selection box appears.

Is there something that I can do to solve the problem? Could I force the GPU to redraw that view with a certain interval, or is there some other solution?

I really like anti-aliasing, but it's hard to use when drawing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Change your shortcut to this:

```
env vblank_mode=0 WINEPREFIX="<prefix>" wine SketchUp.exe
```

Your just adding `vblank_mode=0` between `env` and `WINEPREFIX`

Comment: It seemed to work at first, but after a few seconds I got the same behavior again.